# Cron job: echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches not actualy being written to /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

Tags: bash, kernel, cron

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# If the cache is greater than 5G, echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

CACHE=`grep -w "Cached" /proc/meminfo | awk '{ print $2 }'`
if [[ $CACHE -gt 5000000 ]]
then
        sh -c "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
else
        exit 0
fi
```

I'm running it via cron and seeing it kick off successfully, but it never actually writes the value and is always set to 0. Thus this:

```
total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         64382      27024      37357          0        159       7125
```

Never changes.

I should add that manually running works fine. `/etc/crontab`:
`04 14 * * * root /bin/sh /opt/drop_caches.sh`
(I just put a testing time in there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue.

Since I was calling `/bin/sh` which is `dash`, it does not accept `[[ ]]`. I have tweaked `[[ ]]`.

`[[ $CACHE -gt 5000000 ]]`

I instead used:

`[ $CACHE -gt 5000000 ]`

And it's working fine now.

Comment: Still needs quotes on the variables though. Also your shebang is `bash` so I don't  understand what are you talking about `/bin/sh`

Comment: If you made `/opt/drop_caches.sh` executable you can remove the `/bin/sh` from your crontab entry, which will allow the script to run in bash as you originally intended